# Find out if a very complicated function is always $\le 0$

Tags: inequalities

On $\mathbb{R}^4$ put coordinates $x1,y1,x2,y2$ and consider the function $c:\mathbb{R}^4\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined in the following way:

```
f1 = 1/(2 (x1^2 + y1^2));
f2 = 2/((x1 + Sqrt[3] x2)^2 + (y1 + Sqrt[3] y2)^2);
n = 100000;
f = Log[Exp[n*f1] + Exp[n*f2]]/n;
g = (1/2)*Log[f];
c = -D[D[g, x1], x1] - D[D[g, y1], y1] - D[g, x2]^2 - D[g, y2]^2;
```

I need to find out if the function $c$ is always $\le 0$ or if there are points in which it's $>0$.

This seems like a very complicated task for Mathematica. I tried to use Solve, Reduce and even Plot3D specifying values of $x1$ and $y1$, but everything failed. Is there a better way to do so?

Thank you

Comment: both `Maximize` and `NMaximize` find zeros. (different ones).  This is reasonably convincing but of course not a proof.  You should use `1/2` not `0.5` by the way.

Comment: Thank you! Mathematica won't execute Maximize[c, {x1, y1, x2, y2}] on my pc while NMaximize[c, {x1, y1, x2, y2}] will give a zero as you said. But is it safe to assume that 0 will be a global maximum or is it possible that with a so complicated function something could have gone wrong in the computation of NMaximize?

Comment: unfortunately any numerical method (`NMaximize`) has the potential to miss results, and `Maximize` only tries to find a local max, so no this is not a rigourous proof.

Comment: As there's no analytical solution, (you can't find critical points), this is like proving there are no green Swans. It's the kind of thing you can't formally prove, only disprove.

Comment: This is rather a math problem than an Mma problem. The parameter $n$ is of no importance here. Its value can be taken $1$. Next, the functions f1 and f2 are convex. If one can prove the convexity of g in x1 and y1, then the inequalty holds.